# Getting absolute path to scanned directory and files in recursive function?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, recursion, operating-system

I'm using a function that recursively scans a directory tree. It's doing it's work amazingly, except for 1 major detail. My directory tree looks like this:

```
/testdir--|--folder1--|--pop----quit.mp3
          |           |_drift.mp3
          |           |_drifting.mp3  
          |__folder2----rock--|--paranoid.mp3
                              |__countdown.mp3
```

My code at the moment is this:

```
def craw_func(path):
    """
        Scans the directory recursively, returning a JSON with name,
        type,path and children.
    """
    d = {'name': os.path.basename(path)} 

    if os.path.isdir(path):
        d['type'] = "directory"
        d['path'] = os.curdir # NOT WORKING
        d['children'] = [craw_func(os.path.join(path,x)) for x in os.listdir(path)]
    else:
        d['type'] = "file"
        d['path'] = os.getcwd()  # NOT WORKING EITHER

    return d
```

As you can see by my comment, I tried both, in different positions several times, but neither `os.curdir` nor `os.getcwd()` give the real(absolute) path that I want, both return only the directory on which the script is running.Giving this:

```
{
    "children": [
        {
            "children": [
                {
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "paranoid.mp3",
                            "path": "/home/myname/project_folder/",
                            "type": "file"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "countdown.mp3",
                            "path": "/home/myname/project_folder/",
                            "type": "file"
                        }
                    ],
                    "name": "rock",
                    "path": ".",
                    "type": "directory"
                }
            ],
            "name": "folder2",
            "path": ".",
            "type": "directory"
        },
        {
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "drift.mp3",
                    "path": "/home/myname/project_folder/",
                    "type": "file"
                },
                {
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "quit.mp3",
                            "path": "/home/myname/project_folder/",
                            "type": "file"
                        }
                    ],
                    "name": "pop",
                    "path": ".",
                    "type": "directory"
                },
                {
                    "name": "drifting.mp3",
                    "path": "/home/myname/project_folder/",
                    "type": "file"
                }
            ],
            "name": "folder1",
            "path": ".",
            "type": "directory"
        }
    ],
    "name": "test_dir",
    "path": ".",
    "type": "directory"
}
```

Instead of this(my goal):

```
{
    "children": [
        {
            "children": [
                {
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "paranoid.mp3",
                            "path": "/home/myname/test_dir/folder2/rock",
                            "type": "file"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "countdown.mp3",
                            "path": "/home/myname/test_dir/folder2/rock/",
                            "type": "file"
                        }
                    ],
                    "name": "rock",
                    "path": "/home/myname/test_dir/folder2/",
                    "type": "directory"
                }
            ],
            "name": "folder2",
            "path": "/home/myname/test_dir/",
            "type": "directory"
        },
        {
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "drift.mp3",
                    "path": "/home/myname/test_dir/folder1/",
                    "type": "file"
                },
                {
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "quit.mp3",
                            "path": "/home/myname/test_dir/folder1/pop/",
                            "type": "file"
                        }
                    ],
                    "name": "pop",
                    "path": "/home/myname/test_dir/folder1/",
                    "type": "directory"
                },
                {
                    "name": "drifting.mp3",
                    "path": "/home/myname/test_dir/folder1/",
                    "type": "file"
                }
            ],
            "name": "folder1",
            "path": "/home/myname/test_dir/",
            "type": "directory"
        }
    ],
    "name": "test_dir",
    "path": "/home/myname/",
    "type": "directory"
}
```

What should I use to make it behave how I want? I searched, but couldn't find something in the `os` module that does that.

Comment: Try using `os.path.abspath(path)` instead of the `os.curdir()` and `os.getcwd()`.

Comment: It's up to you..difficult for me to tell how much value it might have to others. I think the core problem was you thinking that something was changing the current directory as your code executed, but that was not the case—all your code does is read and traverse a directory tree starting from a give root.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there were 2 problems with my original function:

1. It used `path` as argument, creating a name clash with the `path` submodule of `os`.
2. I should've used `os.path.abspath(path_to_file)` instead of `os.curdir` and `os.getcwd()` (as pointed by [@martineau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/355230/martineau)).

So my final function is looking like this:

```
def craw_func(path_to_file):
    """
        Scans the directory recursively, returning a JSON with name,
    type,path and children.
    """
    d = {'name': os.path.basename(path_to_file)} 

    if os.path.isdir(path_to_file):
        d['type'] = "directory"
        d['path'] = os.path.abspath(path_to_file)
        d['children'] = [craw_func(os.path.join(path_to_file,x)) for x in os.listdir(path_to_file)]
    else:
        d['type'] = "file"
        d['path'] = os.path.abspath(path_to_file)
    return d
```